# JavaScript doesn't display nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, menubar

The mobile menu Looks good and response to the size change but when you click the menu for mobile it does not pop up or react at all.

```
  <nav>
       <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="mywork.html"> My Work </a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="icon">
      <a href="scripts.js:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += "responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add CSS, or something; as of now it's impossible to tell if it should actually be showing or not.

Comment: perhaps the problem is that the class for myTopnav will either be `topnav` or `topnavresponsive` ... did you need a space? `topnav responsive` ... also, look into using `element.classList.contains` `element.classList.add` `element.classList.remove` as an alternative cleaner looking code :p

Answer (score 0):

You may insert a space before "responsive". Like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```